# ProLiant ML110 G7 Access Bios with USB Control Disable

Tags: hp-proliant, usb

I have a server ProLiant ML110 G7, and need to access the bios on it. The problem is the USB ports are disabled. How can I access it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming there are no PS/2 Ports and so you can't use a USB keyboard to get into the BIOS if the ports are disabled in BIOS.

If you have connected/configured the iLO, you should be able to use that to connect to the remote console and get into the BIOS.

Otherwise, I would look at resetting the BIOS/NVRAM back to factory defaults. If you open up the case and take a look at the motherboard, fine the appropriate DIP Switches to reset the board to defaults. You can find the quick specs for the board [here](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c02830116&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=&prodSeriesId=5075942&prodTypeId=15351). Find the "system maintenance" piece and set the correct switch per the document:

> When the system maintenance switch position 6 is set to the On position, the system is prepared to erase all system configuration settings from both CMOS and NVRAM.
>
> NOTE: Clearing CMOS and/or NVRAM deletes configuration information. Be sure to properly configure the server or data loss could occur.